# passing a string var to a function

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When I run the code below

```
NSString *chemin;
    chemin = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chapitre0%d", [sender tag]];
    NSLog(@"chemin : %@",chemin);

    [detailChapitre loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:chemin ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

I got :
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'

but *chemin is initialized to the right value in the log.

Certainly a noob question,
Thx for your help

Comment: Try braking up the construction of the request into multiple lines to see which aspect of the construction it is failing on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be it, the `chemin` variable might have the correct chapter but the path might be wrong. So when you pass the wrong filepath to `NSURL` it would have returned `null` which inturn would have caused the crash.

First get the absolute path like so -

```
NSString *path   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chapter1" ofType:@"html"];
```

Comment: this returns a nil, it must be my problem. Can't solve it tonight (almost midnight in France). Be back tomorrow

Comment: cool, glad that i got it right. Please upvote if my answer has helped.

Comment: that was it, wrong path! Thx for your help. Cant upvote you, I'm still a noob with no right to vote. thank you is the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

try initializing `chemin` and then release it. like this:

```
NSString *chemin;
chemin = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"chapitre0%d", [sender tag]];
NSLog(@"chemin : %@",chemin);

[detailChapitre loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:chemin ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
[chemin release];
```

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to indicate that the file "chapitre0[whatever].html" is not where you expect it to be. This could be because an incorrect string is being constructed, but it could also just mean your build process isn't sticking the file in the right place or something like that. Look at the string indicated in your NSLog and then look in your built apps's Resources directory to confirm that the file is indeed there and named correctly.